# phpMyAdmin and Apache - Query string - 404 Error

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, phpmyadmin, http2, querystring

When phpMyAdmin tries to access URL as https://example.com/phpmyadmin/server_variables.php&filter=long_query_time, Apache throws a 404 Error.

What might be the problem?

```
The requested URL /phpmyadmin/server_variables.php&filter=long_query_time was not found on this server.
 Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 443
```

When I changed `&` to `?`, everything worked like a charm.
My phpmyadmin.conf looks like this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.htaccess in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted access!"
AuthUserFile /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

phpMyAdmin version is: 4.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug.
Fixed today by https://github.com/nijel

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13561

Answer (score 3):

This is completely normal, because a URL has these components with exactly these delimiters:

```
scheme://host:port/path?query
```

This means that the following URLs are completely different:

- `https://example.com/phpmyadmin/server_variables.php?filter=long_query_time`

  Here, `phpmyadmin/server_variables.php` is *path* and `filter=long_query_time` *query*. Apache can find `server_variables.php` and pass the variables of this `GET` method query to PHP.
- `https://example.com/phpmyadmin/server_variables.php&filter=long_query_time`

  This one has only *path*, `phpmyadmin/server_variables.php&filter=long_query_time`. Because there's no such file, Apache shows error `404`, as it is supposed to do.

The `&` is, instead, used as a delimiter between variables inside a query, e.g. `?foo=123&bar=456`.

Comment: Then why does phpMyAdmin use "wrong" URL format?

Comment: In what page does this take place?

Comment: server_status_advisor.php, when you click on the recommendation and the recommendation contains link to some variable

Comment: I found a quick but nasty fix - I edited /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Advisor.php:330 - replacing server_variables.php in <a href=''> with server_variables.php?foo=bar

Comment: Seems like a bug in PhpMyAdmin. You could send a bug report. Clearly it's something that uses `libraries/Advisor.php:330` rather than itself.

Comment: I reported the bug. Thanks for help and explanation: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13561